# Do C++ and C use the same kind linker?

Tags: c++, c, linker

As the title asks, do C++ and C use the same kind linker in the linking process? Also, for the compilers of C++ and C, does the C++ compiler built upon the C compiler?

Comment: Linking is not a part of the compiling process at all. Linking is a completely different process, and it happens after compilation has finished. If a C++ compiler was built on top of a C compiler, or if it were built from scratch would depend on which compiler we're talking about. Many of them are closed-source, so we don't have a straight forward way of knowing. Also, this is not a C++ or C question.

Comment: As for the gnu compiler suite: yes, gcc and g++ use the same linker: ld

Comment: @VadaPoché why is this not a C++ or C question? It is not about code, it is not about compiling, but without linking most code and most compiling is useless. Imho the tags are completely relevant here

Comment: I guess you meant "kind of" instead of "kind" which has the meaning of sympathetic. However I didnt dare to edit because I couldnt decide to either completely remove it or correct it to "kind of" because thats quite different questions

Comment: Not only C and C++ use the same linker, but (at least with the Microsoft brand), the same linker is used for Fortran, COBOL, and most any other compiled language that Microsoft produces.

Answer (score 9):

Both implementations use the same linker. However, C++ must encode the names and types of the things being linked, in order to support function overloading, so that they cannot be linked with the wrong function. So, if you have two C++ functions like this:

```
 void func( int );
 void func( int, double);
```

then the C++ compiler will generate names for these functions something like `func_int` and `func_int_double`. Exactly what names are generated is compiler specific, and is not specified by the C++ Standard. As C doesn't support overloading, no such mechanism is needed in C, but you do need to turn off this so-called name-mangling if you want to link C++ code with C, which is what the `extern "C"` construct does.